# How to print bash results properly?

Tags: org-mode, bash, print

When I do `$ tree -d -L 3 /usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp` in a bash terminal I get:

```bash
/usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp
├── calc
├── calendar
├── cedet
│   ├── ede
│   ├── semantic
│   │   ├── analyze
│   │   ├── bovine
│   │   ├── decorate
│   │   ├── symref
│   │   └── wisent
│   └── srecode
...
```

But when I execute this block from an org-file:

```
#+begin_src sh 
tree -d -L 3 /usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp
#+end_src
```

I have the following results:

```el
#+RESULTS:
| /usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp |               |          |          |
| ├──                        | calc          |          |          |
| ├──                        | calendar      |          |          |
| ├──                        | cedet         |          |          |
| │                          | ├──           | ede      |          |
| │                          | ├──           | semantic |          |
| │                          | │             | ├──      | analyze  |
| │                          | │             | ├──      | bovine   |
| │                          | │             | ├──      | decorate |
| │                          | │             | ├──      | symref   |
| │                          | │             | └──      | wisent   |
| │                          | └──           | srecode  |          |
...
```

Is it possible to have the results printed properly (i.e. as they look in my terminal)?

Answer (score 3):

Add `:results output` like that:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output
tree -d -L 3 /usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp
#+end_src
```

This overrides the default `:results table` setting and wraps the results (assuming they are not too short - see below) in an `EXAMPLE` block.

The only potential disadvantage is that if the output is shorter than 10 lines[1], then it is not wrapped - instead, it is printed as [literal](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) output, prepending  `:`  to each line.

There are a few ways to treat both short and long output uniformly:

- instead of using `:results output`, one could use `:results output :wrap example` which *always* wraps the output in an `EXAMPLE` block, regardless of its length
- one could use `:results drawer` which wraps the output inside a `:results` drawer, again regardless of its length
- one could customize the variable `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output` which defines the boundary between what is considered short and long output and whose default value is 10. If it is customized to 0, then `:results output` always wraps the results in an `EXAMPLE` block.

---

[1] That's the default value of `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output` which is described towards the end of the answer.

Comment: If I copy the code above into an Emacs buffer (file), how can I run the `tree` command and I see its output?

Comment: The question and the answer are related to org files. So open an org file eg. `C-x C-f test.org RET`, copy paste the block and do `C-c C-c` inside it.

Comment: Bash has to be activated in your init though. Read "Requirements and Setup" section from [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-shell.html). Also, tree CLI has to be installed on your system.

Comment: I have added the contents of my previous comment into the answer, thereby making it as complete as I can make it. I hope you find the additions worthwhile. If not, feel free to revert.

Comment: Thank you @NickD for your addition. Another useful argument is: `:exports results`, which allows the results to be exported (they are not exported by default).

Comment: Yeah, I certainly didn't want to go into all the header arguments: I just wanted to cover a few of the possibilities that were relevant to your question. The rest are covered in the documentation: we don't want to duplicate that on Emacs SE. But if there are specific questions that *can* be answered here, we'll deal with them at that time.